# Objective-c static NSArray initializer

Tags: objective-c, ios, literals

I have this code (small piece from a larger portion - just the troublesome part shown here):

```
#define kSizeLarge @"large"

-(void)determineBestFileSizeWithLimit:(int)limit
{
    static NSString *largeName = kSizeLarge;
    static NSArray *nameArray = @[kSizeLarge];
    ...
}
```

The compiler loves the first static variable and hates the second one, saying

```
Initializer element is not a compile-time constant
```

Removing the static from the second line makes the compiler happy.

What am/was I doing wrong or not getting correctly?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2436730/716216

Comment: Ok, I get it now: those collection static initializers are really just shorthand for the code does the equivalent - `@[a,b,c]` is really just shorthand for `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:a,b,c,nil]`, and since that's not a compile-time constant, the shorthand version isn't either.

Comment: @CubsFanRon: not exactly. array literals are equivalent to a call to the `arrayWithObjects:count:` method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the initializer of your static variable is not a compile-time constant, you need to use another initialization mechanism, such as `dispatch_once`:

```
-(void)determineBestFileSizeWithLimit:(int)limit {
    static NSString *largeName = kSizeLarge;
    static NSArray *nameArray = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        nameArray = @[kSizeLarge];
    });
}
```

Comment: @Joe Yes, that's what happens when everyone models their code after Apple's guidelines :) I keep copying the `dispatch_once` snippet from one of my [earlier answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13099886/335858), so `onceToken` stays the same. This particular question is a "speed typing contest", though :)

Comment: Thanks. It feels like it should be a compile-time constant because everything _is_ both constant and known at compile-time, but I guess it isn't. I was trying to avoid the extra code to manage it's static-ness (that's a word?).

Comment: Oh, I marked this one as the "answer" only because it was first, not because it's any more or less right than the other response (as they're the same).

Comment: @CubsFanRon Actually mine was first, only by seconds but this is fine :)

Comment: Doesn't this mean that every time this method is called, it must perform a check against the `onceToken`?

Comment: @user102008 Yes, that is what dispatch_once will be doing.

Answer (score 4):

`NSArray` literals are not compile-time constants as you have discovered. You should use `dispatch_once` to initialize the array.

```
#define kSizeLarge @"large"

-(void)determineBestFileSizeWithLimit:(int)limit
{
    static NSString *largeName = kSizeLarge;
    static NSArray *nameArray = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        nameArray = @[kSizeLarge];
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't really dig the "dispatch_once" model - I don't find it to be as clear as say `if (!nameArray) {nameArray = @[@kSizeLarge];}`, for example

Comment: That is not thread safe, and the `dispatch_once` only adds 1 more line of code than what you prefer. Anyone familiar with Objective-C should have basic knowledge of GCD and blocks, if they don't yet the should learn.

Comment: I'm not really concerned lines of code as a metric - I'm more concerned about "meaning of the code" as a meme. My code is simple and direct, but since it has this latent defect waiting to bite me in the a**, I think I'll learn a new meme. Then this new code will become simple and direct in my head, which is something I do care about.

Comment: Let me further test my understanding: if I have a static variable, either limited to the file scope or a function/method scope, if it has a non-compile-time value I should use the `dispatch_once` approach to initialize it. Should I also be doing this for non-static variables (e.g., properties), particularly those that are created via lazy instantiation?

Comment: No, do not use this for non-static variables because they would only get assigned on the first run. You are correct that you should use this for initializing any static non-compile-time constants.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I'm seeing this more clearly. It is convenient that Xcode comes with a pre-installed snippet for this meme.

Comment: Just a brief follow-up triggered by another answer contribution: I now dig the "dispatch_once" model after using it for a bit. It makes it so I no longer have to think about race condition potential - it will be done exactly once and now I can move on to different problems. I wish I could up-vote you again. :)